# Aligning string to center of .txt file

Tags: java, alignment, text-files

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

public class fileprint {

public static void main(String args[]){

    String title;
    String desc;

    //scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //--file--//
    String fileName = "print.txt";

    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
      writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    //--end--//

    System.out.print("Enter a title:");
    title = sc.nextLine();

    writer.println(title);

      do
      {
        System.out.println("Enter a description: ");
        desc = sc.nextLine();

        writer.println(desc);

      }while(!desc.equals("END"));

        writer.close();

    }//end main
}//end class
```

Above is my code, I have successfully completed the program and it's functioning as intended. However I would like the printed string (title) in .txt file to be aligned in the center of my description. My current output in the .txt file is like this: [image: Screen print]

As you can see, the word "title" is at the most left of the .txt file and I would like it to be in the center of "cats and dogs" and "are best friends." I am also trying to remove the word "END" from the .txt file, this was not intended but `writer.print(value)` has taken in "END" and has printed it to the .txt file. What are my options here?

Comment: First, collect the title and description lines from the user, but **don't print anything out yet**.  Once you have all the description lines, find the length of the longest one.  Subtract the length of the title from the length of the longest description line and divide the result by 2.  Print your title indented by that many spaces.  And, of course, print out the description lines after, with no indent.

Comment: @KevinAnderson How do I only save the description of the user without printing it out? I tried printing everything out last but the sentinel value "END" overwrites everything in "desc" and I end up only printing the word END.

Comment: Use a list, such as `ArrayList`.